# File not found No content provider Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Why is this throwing a file not found exception when it's giving me the stupid download url from my Firebase Storage meaning THERE IS a file, right?

[image]

```
try {


Tasks.await(FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("cutout").child(name).child(name + "_temporary.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        try {
                            Bitmap bitmapToDetect = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                            Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmapToDetect.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Comment: `MediaStore` provides access to files that exist on the device.  You can't use it to download a file from FirebaseStorage.

Comment: So what do you want me to do